# Ajax Google Forms

Tags: javascript, ajax

Как проверить статус код запроса?
Есть форма, отправляю её данные на google docs, используя google forms, нужно проверить в ajax запросе статус код и сделать кое-какие действия.

HTML:

```
 <form>
    <input type="text" name="entry.894071397" placeholder="<?=$vars[13][$lng]?>*">
    <input type="tel" name="entry.1658110892" placeholder="<?=$vars[14][$lng]?>*">
    <input type="email" name="entry.527245786" placeholder="<?=$vars[15][$lng]?>*">                               
    <button type="button" class="submit send-email"><?=$vars[16][$lng]?></button>
    <div id="result_1"></div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.send-email').click(function(){
        var formData = $(this).parent('form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url : 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1c84auFO2J21SoAXeHKZKB7eVwzfcpmo0BabceeYHG_I/formResponse',
            method : 'POST',
            data : formData,
        });
    });
});
```

Вот такая ошибка в консоли (скорее всего, из-за нее и не могу получить статус код):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1c84auFO2J21SoAXeHKZKB7eVwzfcpmo0BabceeYHG_I/formResponse. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mebelive.md' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Добавьте в метод .ajax: dataType: 'jsonp'. Поправил свой ответ.

Comment: Refused to execute script from 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1c84auFO2J21SoAXeHKZKB7eVwzfcpmo0BabceeYHG_…860494&entry.894071397=&entry.1658110892=&entry.527245786=&_=1461050860495' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: Сейчас запрос вообще не выполняется

Comment: Попробуйте dataType: 'xml'

Comment: Тоже не работает!

Comment: У вас проблема с самой отправкой формы. Что-то не так. Статусы работают верно. Ответ мой верен, просто сейчас нужно поправить саму отправку. Попытаюсь решить вашу проблему

Comment: Отправка работает нормально,запросы посылаются,данные в документ записываются

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mebelive.md' is therefore not allowed access. Вас это не смущает? Вам сервер не дает нужных заголовков.

Answer (score 1):

Статус Ajax-запроса можно отследить таким образом:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1c84auFO2J21SoAXeHKZKB7eVwzfcpmo0BabceeYHG_I/formResponse',
     method: 'POST',
     data: formData,
     statusCode: {
         200: function(response) {
             alert('200');
         },
         201: function(response) {
             alert('201');
         },
         400: function(response) {
             alert('400');
         },
         404: function(response) {
             alert('401');
         }
     },
     success: function() {
         alert('Успешно');
     },
 });
```

Comment: Пробовал не работает

Comment: Тогда что Вам нужно конкретно сделать? Какие действия?

Comment: Простой редирект не более